# Converting Python Script to C++

Tags: python, c++

I have a Python script that runs properly. But I need to implement this script to a root macro in C++. As I am not really familiar with python syntax, I am having a hard time.

```
ATOMIC_MASS = 931.4940954e6  


class ReducedMomentum:
    def __init__(self, mass):
        self.mass = mass

    def __call__(self, kinetic_energy):
        return math.sqrt(kinetic_energy * (kinetic_energy + 2 * self.mass)) / self.mass


class MassFraction:
    def __init__(self, tritium_mass, electron_mass):
        self.tritium_mass = tritium_mass
        self.electron_mass = electron_mass

    def __call__(self, spectator_mass):
        return spectator_mass / (spectator_mass + self.tritium_mass + 2 * self.electron_mass)


class Ktilde:
    def __init__(self, alpha_1, tritium_mass, electron_mass_eV):
        self.alpha_1 = alpha_1
        self.mass_fraction = MassFraction(tritium_mass, electron_mass_eV / ATOMIC_MASS)
        self.reduced_momentum = ReducedMomentum(electron_mass_eV)

    def __call__(self, spectator_mass, electron_kinetic_energy):
        return self.alpha_1 * self.mass_fraction(spectator_mass) * self.reduced_momentum(electron_kinetic_energy)
```

I have understood  the first few lines but the main problem is the following part:

```
        self.mass_fraction = MassFraction(tritium_mass, electron_mass_eV / ATOMIC_MASS)
```

ant the line below this. How can I convert these lines to C++? What do they exactly mean mathematically?

The familiar line comes again a few times as:

```
    ktilde = Ktilde(alpha_1, spectator_masses, electron_mass)
    mass_spectator = parse_spectator_mass(args, parser)
    ktilde_value = ktilde(mass_spectator, args.energy)
    print('{:.4f}'.format(ktilde_value))
```

This is probably rather trivial but I couldn't find any solution on Google. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In my opinion, the python writer is over-using \_\_call\_\_ (and also really lacking doc strings for what the parameters are), but hopefully you've got a better idea of at least the class mechanics. The conversion should actually be fairly one-to-one, just get the typing of arguments right (I think they are all floats or doubles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the class calls itself like that it's the __call__ method in the class that it is calling, like operator(). __init__ is like a constructor and is called when the class is instantiated, so everything in init is available by the time the class gets to __call__.

```
class ReducedMomentum:
    # here is where an instance of the object calls itself
    def __call__(self, kinetic_energy):
        """Example
           reduced_momentum = ReducedMomentum(5)
           reduction = reduced_momentum(5)
        """
        return math.sqrt(kinetic_energy * (kinetic_energy + 2 * self.mass)) / self.mass
```

So for your Ktilde class, for example

```
class Ktilde:
    def __init__(self, alpha_1, tritium_mass, electron_mass_eV):
        """Constructor needing above arguments
           alpha_1: float?
           tritium_mass: float?
           electron_mass_eV: float?

           Example:
           k_tilde = Ktilde(1., 1., 1.)  # initialize with params
           some_spectator_mass = 2.  # some other relevant numbers
           some_electron_KE = 302.1
           calculation = k_tilde(some_spectator_mass, some_electron_KE)  # uses the __call__ method in this class
        """
        self.alpha_1 = alpha_1
        self.mass_fraction = MassFraction(tritium_mass, electron_mass_eV / ATOMIC_MASS)
        self.reduced_momentum = ReducedMomentum(electron_mass_eV)

    def __call__(self, spectator_mass, electron_kinetic_energy):
        return self.alpha_1 * self.mass_fraction(spectator_mass) * self.reduced_momentum(electron_kinetic_energy)
```

So this does

```
    ktilde = Ktilde(alpha_1, spectator_masses, electron_mass)  # ktilde instance
    mass_spectator = parse_spectator_mass(args, parser)  # some function to get mass of spectator
    ktilde_value = ktilde(mass_spectator, args.energy)  # uses __call__ method of KTilde, args is some object (maybe from argparser) that has an energy attribute
    print('{:.4f}'.format(ktilde_value))
```

Comment: "When the class calls itself"? Do you mean the line `MassFraction(a,b)`? That's calling the initializer

Comment: @SirGuy, oh, good catch, that's calling the init in this case. Got lost in OPs code break-up.

Comment: `__call__` in Python is like `operator()` in C++.

Comment: So the line 'self.mass_fraction = MassFraction(a,b) calls the initializer' class MassFraction and replacing self.tritium_mass with a and self.electron_mass with b. Did I understand correct?

Comment: @Alert, that is kind of correct, the "constructor" for class Ktilde takes parameters needed for MassFraction and ReducedMomentum to make class instances as attributes assigned to an instance of Ktilde.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a great help! I've managed to convert it to C++ thanks to your answers.